# "Before" implies a change?

Tags: prepositions

"Before" doesn't normally imply a change, but in the following sentence, does it imply a change, like "until" does? Does "before" equal "until"?

> Before last week, I always believed in Santa Claus , but now I don't.

> Before last week I'd always believed in Santa Claus, but then l realized he wasn't real.

Comment: What leads you to doubt the reality of Santa Claus?

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, *before* means the same as *until*, but it's not as good a word as *until*, since that specifically means up to a point in time.

The word *always* isn't necessary if you use *until*, which implies at all points in time up to last week.